# Infinite loop in appium inspector

Tags: xcode, appium, inspector

I'm stuck with this issue - I have already tried everything from the internet. When I start appium inspector, it opens my app on my real (connected) device iPhone, but then nothing happens with appium inspector. It's just loading (Gathering initial app source…).
I use: 
Xcode Version 12.5 beta (12E5220o)
Appium Desktop Version: 1.20.2; Electron: 7.2.4; Node.js: 12.8.1
macOS Big Sur Version 11.0.1
I've tried hide app on background then open it and refresh appium inspector, I've tried run appium from terminal and new session window in appium desktop and use following instructions, but then I get error about WebDriverAgent error 65. 
Again: inspector runs my app on my real device and my test from idea working fine on my real device with this Appium session, but inspector is empty [Appium inspector loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaZwt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

- Start Appium server from the command line (1.15.0-beta.1)
- Start the Appium Desktop app.
- Do NOT click "Start Server"
- Launch the new session window (go up to "Appium desktop" (mac) or
  "File" (windows) and click new session from the menu)
- Open the "Custom Server" tab of the new session window
- Enter your local Appium server host and port (localhost / 4723)
- Enter your capabilities Start the session as normal. This will start a session using the Appium instance you have running on the command line

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).